# What does "Result" means in a .map operator of an Observable obtained from an http.get request in nativescript/angular

Tags: json, angular, nativescript, reactivex

I'm doing the nativescript/angular tutorial and I found something in the code that I don't understand and want some clarification.

In chapter 4 (Nativescript modules) when they do a http.get resquest to retrieve the Grocery List and they get the Observable I notice that it is passed throught some maps operator, here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

import { Config } from "../config";
import { Grocery } from "./grocery";

@Injectable()
export class GroceryListService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  load() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + Config.token);

    return this.http.get(Config.apiUrl + "Groceries", {
      headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(data => {
      let groceryList = [];
      data.Result.forEach((grocery) => { //<------HERE
        groceryList.push(new Grocery(grocery.Id, grocery.Name));
      });
      return groceryList;
    })
    .catch(this.handleErrors);
  }

  handleErrors(error: Response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
}
```

My question is, what does "Result" means in the second .map

Why they don't simply put

```
data.forEach((grocery) => {
```

I ask because I'm not sure if it is an object property of the resulting observable from .map(res => res.json) or something else.

Could you point me to some documentation of where does that "Result" come from and what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this line `.map(res => res.json())` parses the response body into a json object. Then the second `map` allows access to this json object under `data` argument. The json object represented by `data` is actually a wrapper around the actual response result data using the `Result` as the key mapped to the data returned from the backend which follows this security advise [HERE](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Always_return_JSON_with_an_Object_on_the_outside). So `data.Result` is just a key mapped to the actual data returned from the backend. The backend could have used a different name for the key, e.g. secret, then you would do `data.secret` to obtain the data returned from the server